# Alternate div styles within separate components Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to apply a striped look to a few divs. My structure is below. Each component is a new instance that is being rendered in an ngFor loop, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataSet>
  <component1 [data]="data"></component1>
</div>
```

Rendered HTML

```
<component1>
  <div>
    <div class="style-this-div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</component1>

<component1>
  <div>
    <div class="style-this-div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</component1>

<component1>
  <div>
    <div class="style-this-div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</component1>
```

Here is what I have tried:

CSS

```
  div[class^="style-this-div"]:nth-of-type(odd) {background-color: #efeeee;}
  div[class^="style-this-div"]:nth-of-type(even) {background-color: #efeeee;}

  .style-this-div:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #efeeee;}
  .style-this-div:nth-child(even) {background-color: #efeeee;}
```

When I use the odd selectors, the gray background color is applied to all of them. I'm trying to get them to alternate colors. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: I believe in order for `nth-of-type` to work correctly, the elements would need to share the same parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to the component container like i did below. ANd use the "nth-child" odd and even

```css
.component1:nth-child(odd)  .style-this-div{
  background: red;
}
.component1:nth-child(even) .style-this-div{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<component1 class="component1">
  <div>
    <div class="style-this-div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</component1>

<component1 class="component1">
  <div>
    <div class="style-this-div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</component1>

<component1 class="component1">
  <div>
    <div class="style-this-div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
  </component1>
```

Comment: It worked when I added class="component" to the outer div with the ngFor loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap your content in a div with an ID of component1, component2, etc...
and Class of component. The reason the nth-child isn't working is because it's looking for the odd ".style-this-div" in each component and not in the document.This way we target the first component class of it's kind and style the div inside.

If you can't change the structure just add the class of .component to your top level element and the css below should still work.

Let me know if you have questions.

HTML

```
<div id="component1" class="component">
  <div>
    <div class="style-this-div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="component2" class="component">
  <div>
    <div class="style-this-div">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .component:nth-child(odd) .style-this-div {background-color: #efeeee;}
  .component:nth-child(even) .style-this-div {background-color: #fff;}
```

[Codepen Here](https://codepen.io/alcoven/pen/KmZMxP)

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me. I have updated my question to give more detail into my structure. I'm still getting odd divs that are all gray. I tried adding id and class to the component tag itself, and also to a div in the component template. What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Austin Did you look at my Codepen? Not sure what's missing. Do you have a live link to your dev site or somewhere I can poke around?